# URL rewrite - Sitecore on IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, sitecore

I have a Sitecore application running on top of IIS 8.5. I want to redirect/rewrite from #1 to #2 URL.

1. http://mywebsite.com/a/a1/webpage.aspx
2. http://mywebsite.com/a/a2/webpage.aspx

I tried to do on IIS-URL rewrite level, it just doesn't work and nothing happen.

```xml
<rule name="redirect_a1_to_a2" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="a/a1/" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="a/a1(/?)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mywebsite.com/a/a2" />
</rule>
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to enable that rule. Change `enabled="false"` to `enabled="true"`

Comment: @MarekMusielak: You should put this down as an answer to be accepted!

Comment: @JayS comment converted into an answer. Thanks for your tip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is correct. Then only thing you need to do is to enable the rule.

Just change:

```
enabled="false"
```

to

```
enabled="true"
```